# Converting POJO to JSON using Mule 3

Tags: json, spring, mule

I'm getting started using Mule, but the documentation is all over the place.  I am trying to write a fairly simple flow.  Here is what I'd like it to do:

1. Call existing Spring service that returns a POJO
2. Take POJO from service and convert to JSON
3. Display JSON via a URL

I can't find any definitive documentation on how and if this can be done in Mule 3.  It seems like it should be a fairly straight forward flow.

Thanks.

Comment: spring can do all that without mule. It uses jackson to convert a pojo to json

Comment: Is the Spring service JAX-RS annotated? What method do you need to call on it? Where will the arguments to this call come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [simple service](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Simple+Service+Pattern) pattern. If the POJO is JAX-RS annotated, it's as simple as:

```
<pattern:simple-service name="weather-report-rsc"
         address="http://localhost:6099/rest"
         component-class="org.mule.test.integration.tck.WeatherReportResource"
         type="jax-rs" />
```

Check the other usage scenarios at the provided URL.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a Jersey endpoint. Create a service that returns the POJO specifies that it is in JSON format. As NimChimpsky pointed out, the POJO will automagically be converted to JSON by Jackson.

The mule part of this is documented in the Jersey section I think.